# Node JS Error: Invalid cipher

Tags: node.js, encryption, bookshelf.js

I am trying to use [Bookshelf-encrypted-columns](https://github.com/scoutforpets/bookshelf-encrypt-columns) for aes encrypt my data, for that I need key, and cipher. Key is not a problem but while creating "cipher" I am getting this error below:

```
"Error: Invalid cipher: 78c2527b394d0d4016571fea85e40c52"
```

Code below requires cipher:

```
bookshelf.plugin(encryptColumns, {
    cipher: getCipher(config.encrypt.aesKey),
    key: config.encrypt.aesKey
});
```

Function that creates cipher using nodejs crypto createCipheriv

```
function getCipher (key) { 
        // generate initialization vector
        let iv = new Buffer.alloc(16); // fill with zeros

        // encrypt data
        return crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
}
```

Is there a solution to create cipher?

Answer (score 1):

The `cipher` value is supposed to be a string describing the algorithm to use, not an instance of a `Cipher` object.

For reference, see [the default cipher value](https://github.com/scoutforpets/bookshelf-encrypt-columns/blob/1dafc88d9dcee66953f43a76bac50e967f91f70d/src/index.js#L22) and [the value passed to the plugin instantiation call for the unit tests](https://github.com/scoutforpets/bookshelf-encrypt-columns/blob/1dafc88d9dcee66953f43a76bac50e967f91f70d/test/index.js#L20).

In your code, try using this:

```
bookshelf.plugin(encryptColumns, {
    cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
    key: config.encrypt.aesKey
});
```

Comment: This leads to another error: Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
    at Decipher.final (crypto.js:183:26)

Comment: I am trying to encrypt user data like phone numbers, emails, and credit card details to be precise.

Comment: The next thing I'd suspect is the key value. Can you provide any context about what it's being set to?

Comment: For example this is what I was going to insert in to db: {
 "phone": "4575568512",
 "device_unique_id": "Manisdf123",
 "device_name": "dasdasdaddsdsdEdited",
 "device_model": "ipadEdited",
 "device_type": "ipadEdited",
 "device_token": "dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdfEdited",
 "device_version": 1.1
}

Comment: When I am trying insert into table I am getting this error below: TypeError: Cipher data must be a string or a buffer, while fetching data I am getting the above error which is in the first comment

Comment: First, if you haven't successfully inserted data, there's no reason to expect the fetch operation to work.

Comment: After a bit of research, it seems the problem may be that you're using an algorithm that requires an IV (initialization vector), but the `bookshelf-encrypt-columns` library doesn't support that. It's [using deprecated methods](https://github.com/scoutforpets/bookshelf-encrypt-columns/blob/master/src/crypto-util.js) to create the [`Cipher`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) and [`Decipher`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options) objects

Comment: Seeing that library hasn't been touched in 3 years, your options probably are to either use the default cipher that it's been tested with, request that the library be updated or update the library yourself.